# Methode remove doesn't work in leaflet0.7.7

Tags: leaflet, draw

I'm looking for a solution in leaflet0.7.7 for the following code:

```
var currentlyDisplayedRectangles = []; //Used in CorridorHandler

drawRoute = function(route) {
  route = new L.Polyline(L.PolylineUtil.decode(route)); // OSRM polyline decoding
  boxes = L.RouteBoxer.box(route, this.wideroad);
  var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds([]);
    if (currentlyDisplayedRectangles) {
      for (var i = 0; i < currentlyDisplayedRectangles.length; i++) {
        //currentlyDisplayedRectangles[i].remove(); //Doesn't work in leaflet0.7.7
        console.log(currentlyDisplayedRectangles[i]);
      }
    } else {
      currentlyDisplayedRectangles = [];
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
      var displayedRectangle = L.rectangle(boxes[i], {color: "#ff7800", weight: 1}).addTo(this.map);
      currentlyDisplayedRectangles.push(displayedRectangle);
      bounds.extend(boxes[i]);
    }
    this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
    return route;
  }; //End drawRoute()
```

This works perfectly in leaflet1.0.0 but not in leaflet0.7.7

```
currentlyDisplayedRectangles[i].remove();
```

this will give an error that function is not available.

For some reason I can actually not update to leaflet1.0.0 because a lot of other stuff doesn't work anymore and for the time beeing I have to accept this.

Later on I'm willing to update for sure. But meanwhile I need a solution for the previous version of leaflet.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

In Leaflet 0.7.x, the [`Ilayer` abstract class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#ilayer) simply does not have a `remove` method.

Compare that to the [`remove` method of the `Layer` class](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layer-method) in Leaflet 1.0.

As an alternative, use the [`removeLayer` method from the `Map` class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-removelayer).

Comment: well, I do not have any idea how to implement it. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Guido When you create a layer, keep a reference to it.  E.g., `var polyline = L.polyline(dataArray, {color: 'blue'}).addTo(map);` Then to remove it, use: `map.removeLayer(polyline);`

Comment: @GuidoHollenstein Thank you for your feedback to Ivan. Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to **accept** the answer that helped you solve your issue.